# Unable to apply data patch for module Graphql_Assignment. Original exception message: Patch \Setup\Patch\Data\CustomAttribute1 cannot be applied twice

Tags: magento2

In magento2.4.4 i have encounter some strange error :

Unable to apply data patch GraphQL\Assignment\Setup\Patch\Data\CustomAttribute1 for module Graphql_Assignment. Original exception message: Patch GraphQL\Assignment\Setup\Patch\Data\CustomAttribute1 cannot be applied twice.

Setup\Patch\Data is runs only one time right ?
then how it is running for second time when i run setup:upgrade command ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with the namespace.

Since the module name is `Graphql_Assignment`, so that namespace should contain `Graphql` not `GraphQL`

**Incorrect**

```
GraphQL\Assignment\Setup\Patch\Data
```

**Correct**

```
Graphql\Assignment\Setup\Patch\Data
```